# Don't wait for form submit redirect

Tags: form-submit, cypress, implicit

i'm trying to test an application using cypress. I have an odd scenario where i have an html form with an action tag, some fields in the form and then a button for submit it. 
I'm filling out all the fields in the form and click the button for submission, but i'm getting this error: [image: 1]

I don't wanna wait for the response, cause in this odd case the response is redirecting for a page i don't have access and the test fails, i'm just want a check the form submission response by checking something simple, for instance the response status.

Any help will be welcome...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below `cy.request()` method. I don't know if there is any authorization needed for your request. Give a try as below and let me know.

```
it('Check response status', function () {
    cy.request({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'url_here',
        form: true, 
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json",          
         },
    }).then((response) => {
        expect(response.status).to.eq(200);   
    })
})
```